# Problems importing .svg files into Word

Tags: inkscape, microsoft-word-365

I am able to copy and paste or insert .svg files from Inkscape into Word but when I do so some of the text becomes displaced. When I try to convert the image to an editable format, all of the text is lost. For instance, minus signs drop from the middle of a number to the bottom of the number and numbers adjacent to decimals are displaced.

Has anyone discovered a workaround?

Comment: Take a screenshot and paste it?

Comment: Thank you but then the image comes in fuzzy and not as an SVG

Answer (score 1):

Edit: just removed my previous answer, and re-posted using a different user name

The only way to get high quality pictures from Inkscape into Word is to use the export functionality from Inkscape, to export to .png files. Set the resolution sufficiently high in Inkscape, like 600 dpi, and import the picture in Word as a bitmap. You won't be able to edit the picture in Word, but you mind want to let go of that utopic idea anyway ;-). Not just because the SVG interpreter in Word is subpar, but because there will always be issues, even between Excel and Word.

Comment: This would rasterize the SVG file and is not a good solution, shame on Microsoft for not allowing direct vector imports in word.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success saving as EMF from Inkscape and then inserting into Word. Vector format is retained.

Comment: For this to work correctly, you need to enable the "Convert texts to paths" option when saving as EMF in Inkscape (this option is enabled by default).